# How to count rows which has group by clause?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

I have written the following query which used `group by` clause

```
select MAX(r.network->>"$[0].name") , s.server, MAX(s.ipAddr),
    from table1 e
    inner join table2 s
        on e.objectId  = s.envId
    inner join resources r
        on e.objectId  = r.envId    
    inner join tpgs g
        on e.accountId  = g.objectId      
    inner join msgTable a
        on a.id  = (select max(a.id) from msgTable a where a.logId = s.AuditId)  
    GROUP BY s.server 
    ORDER BY dateSubmitted DESC ;
```

I want to `count` the number of rows returned by the above query.

The following query is not giving the `count`

```
select count(*)
    from table1 e
    inner join table2 s
        on e.objectId  = s.envId
    inner join resources r
        on e.objectId  = r.envId    
    inner join tpgs g
        on e.accountId  = g.objectId      
    inner join msgTable a
        on a.id  = (select max(a.id) from msgTable a where a.logId = s.AuditId)  
    GROUP BY s.server;
```

Comment: *What* is it that you want to count? Do you mean the number of rows returned by the first query?

Comment: Posting a broken query without any explanation what you want to accomplish will not help us help you.  What  do you want to count???

Comment: The query is incomplete but it is not broken. @GMB has helped with it and it is exactly what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to count the number of rows that is returned by the aggregate query.

If so, then you need another level of aggregation, ie turn your query to a subquery, and then count in the outer query:

```
select count(*) no_records
from (
    select 1          
    from table1 e
    inner join table2 s
        on e.objectId  = s.envId
    inner join resources r
        on e.objectId  = r.envId    
    inner join tpgs g
        on e.accountId  = g.objectId      
    inner join msgTable a
        on a.id  = (select max(a.id) from msgTable a where a.logId = s.AuditId)  
    group by s.server
) t;
```

Note: since all we want is count how many records we get, we do not really need the other computation in the `SELECT` clause; `SELECT 1` is enough.